# Current iteration in scipy odeint

Tags: python, scipy

I am using Scipy's odeint (`scipy.integrate.odeint`) to solve some ODEs for me, and all is working nice and well. However, I'd now like to include another time-dependent set of data into my calculations, i.e. for `t = [0, 1, 2, 3]` I've got data `z = [0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.22]` to be included in the calculations. I can pass the vector as an argument, but that gives me the entire vector for every time step. Is there an efficient way of getting the current step (iterator) of the calculation? That way I can obtain `z[i]` for the i-th time step. Note that `z` has the length of `t`, and that both can contain several thousands of elements.

Thanks

A very simple example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def func(y, t, z):
    # I'd like to get the i-th element
    # of z, corresponding to t[i]
    return y+z[i]

result = odeint(func, [0], t, (z,))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work-around solution for this problem is using the more generic [`scipy.integrate.ode`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html) function. This function has several integration schemes build-in, and you have more control of what happens during each iteration. See the example below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode

def func(t, y, z):
    return y+z

t = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 100)
dt = t[1]-t[0]
z = np.random.rand(100)
output = np.empty_like(t)
r = ode(func).set_integrator("dop853")
r.set_initial_value(0, 0).set_f_params(z[0])

for i in xrange(len(t)):
    r.set_f_params(z[i])
    r.integrate(r.t+dt)
    output[i] = r.y
```

During each iteration, the solver's value of `z` is updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For ode solvers, you can use an [interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) for time-varying inputs. In this case:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

t_arr = np.array([0,1,2,3])
z_arr = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.22])
finterp = interp1d(t_arr,z_arr,fill_value='extrapolate') #create interpolation function

def func(y,t,z):
    print(t)
    zt = finterp(t) # call interpolation at time t
    return y+zt

result = odeint(func, [0], t_arr, (z_arr,))
```

However, the solver in odeint may request time instants beyond t_arr (in your case at 3.028), so you have to specify values for z beyond t=3 or allow for extrapolation with fill_value (as shown above). Just be careful when selecting a kind of interpolation, to reflect the behavior that you expect.